# How to make multiple column headers in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to split the `QTreeWidget` horizontally with multiple column headers. Here is the photoshoped concept:

[image]

So different "by nature" `QTreeWidget`'s items could be listed under the dedicated column headers. If inserting the multiple headers is not an option I would like to know if there are any other ways to achieve a similar result.

(on an image-example the headers have the same name. That just because I copied/pasted the same screenshot. In "real-world" scenario the headers will be different).

Comment: Do you want simply a set of horizontal cells with altered appearance, or do you want the header rows to be able to do highlighting, sorting etc.? Multiple TreeWidgets might be the easiest answer.

Comment: Multiple TreeWidgets probably is probably what I need (the header rows to be able to do highlighting, sorting etc).